# Get temp creds in Lambda that live longer than the lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, credentials

So, I'm inside an AWS lambda function. I need to return temp creds from an API endpoint, so that an upload can be performed from browser directly to S3.

The files can be very large, hundreds of gigabytes, so the creds need to last a long time. What's the easiest way to get these type of creds inside a lambda?

Comment: Typically, Lambda does not use creds to invoke AWS Service operations. Instead Lambda uses an IAM Role that has permissions to invoke a given service, From your statement, you seems to want to upload file to an Amazon S3 bucket. There are other ways to do this instead of exposing creds. One option is to use a Pre-signed URL. (However, I have never tried to upload files that are as large as you are describing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that you need to assume a role, as I describe in [this blog post](https://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/two-buckets-and-a-lambda-a-pattern-for-file-processing/). A key part of that post is using a session policy to scope the assumed role to a single key on S3.

However, if it takes more than an hour to upload the file, that solution won't work as written, because a Lambda can't assume another role with a requested duration > one hour (see [role chaining](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_terms-and-concepts.html#iam-term-role-chaining)), a limit that [can't be increased](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-role-chaining-limit/).

This means that you need to create a user that can assume the role, and make that user's long-term credentials available to the Lambda (typically via Secrets Manager). Once you've retrieved those credentials, use them to create an STS client (you don't say what language you're using, and I typically use Python, so that's what's shown):

```
sts_client = boto3.client(
    'sts',
    aws_access_key_id=stored_access_key,
    aws_secret_access_key=stored_secret_key)
```

Then with those credentials you can assume a role that can write to the file. In following the blog post, the base role has permissions to write to any file on S3, and the session policy limits the assumed role to the specific file:

```
session_policy = json.dumps({
    'Version': '2012-10-17',
    'Statement': [
        {
            'Effect': 'Allow',
            'Action': 's3:PutObject',
            'Resource': f"arn:aws:s3:::{BUCKET}/{KEY}"
        }
    ]
})

response = sts_client.assume_role(
    RoleArn=ASSUMABLE_ROLE_ARN,
    RoleSessionName="example",
    Policy=session_policy,
    DurationSeconds=12 * 3600
)

# these are the credentials that you'd pass to the client application

limited_access_key = response['Credentials']['AccessKeyId']
limited_secret_key = response['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey']
limited_session_token = response['Credentials']['SessionToken']
```

12 hours is enough time to transfer 500 GB over a 100 mbps connection. If you need to more time than that, then you'll have to create an actual user and return its credentials. You can attach an inline policy to this user to limit its access to the single file (serving the same purpose as the session policy in this example). But since you're limited to 5,000 IAM users in an account, this is not something that you want to do on a regular basis.

Comment: I marked yours as the accepted answer. It's not exactly what I did but it would work just as well. We ended up creating an IAM user, creating an STS client and then getting a federated token where we could specify duration seconds of the token as well as a hefty IAM security policy to lock it down very specifically.