# Get temp creds in Lambda that live longer that 1 hour and avoid Role Chaining issue

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, okta-api, aws-iam-policy

**Issue**: My use case is to authenticate user programatically in Lambda and fetch his credentials using [AssumeRoleWithSAML](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRoleWithSAML.html) API. Post this I want to use this credential to assume another role in lambda and generate temporary credentials that live longer than 1 hour and don't fall in to role chaining issue. The solution described in stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69527413/get-temp-creds-in-lambda-that-live-longer-than-the-lambda?newreg=4d7d02c3c1d243e1b61e3f4da307f5f4) works but I don't want to create an IAM user, instead I want to use federated user credentials to achieve this. Below is my code but I am getting error. Any help is appreciated.

```
import requests
import boto3
import base64

def authenticate_with_okta(username, password, okta_org_url, okta_app_url):
    okta_authn_url = f"{okta_org_url}/api/v1/authn"

    # Send a POST request to the Okta Authn endpoint to authenticate the user
    response = requests.post(okta_authn_url, json={
        "username": username,
        "password": password
    })
    print(response)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        # Extract the SAML assertion from the response JSON
        auth_response = response.json()
        saml_assertion = auth_response.get('sessionToken')
        if saml_assertion:
            return saml_assertion
    else:
        print(f"Authentication failed. Status code: {response.status_code}")
    return None

def decode_saml_assertion(saml_assertion):
    try:
        decoded_saml = base64.b64decode(saml_assertion)
        return decoded_saml
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error decoding SAML Assertion: {e}")
        return None

# Decode and print the SAML Assertion
decoded_saml_assertion = decode_saml_assertion
print(decoded_saml_assertion)

def assume_role_with_saml(saml_assertion, role_arn, principal_arn, region_name='us-east-1'):
    print("Received SAML Assertion:")
    print(saml_assertion)

    client = boto3.client('sts', region_name=region_name)
    response = client.assume_role_with_saml(
        RoleArn=role_arn,
        PrincipalArn=principal_arn,
        SAMLAssertion=saml_assertion
    )

    print("STS Response:")
    print(response)

    return response['Credentials']

def main():
    # Replace with your Okta credentials and configuration
    okta_username = "MyOktaUser@lab.com"
    okta_password = "MyComplexPassword"
    okta_org_url = "https://mydomain.okta.com"  # Replace with your Okta domain URL
    okta_app_url = "https://mydomain/home/amazon_appstream/0oa8alauh3v3ise4C5d7/aln1al3ek55Es08M81d8"     # Replace with your Okta app URL

    # Replace with your AWS role ARN and principal ARN
    aws_role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/Test_Role"
    aws_principal_arn = "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:saml-provider/Okta"

    # Step 1: Authenticate with Okta and get SAML Assertion
    saml_assertion = authenticate_with_okta(okta_username, okta_password, okta_org_url, okta_app_url)
    if not saml_assertion:
        print("Failed to obtain SAML Assertion.")
        return

    # Step 2: Use SAML Assertion to Assume AWS Role and get temporary credentials
    try:
        credentials = assume_role_with_saml(saml_assertion, aws_role_arn, aws_principal_arn)
        print("Temporary credentials fetched successfully!")
        print("Access Key ID:", credentials['AccessKeyId'])
        print("Secret Access Key:", credentials['SecretAccessKey'])
        print("Session Token:", credentials['SessionToken'])
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error assuming AWS role:", e)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Error**

```
Received SAML Assertion:
20111Fw2lcP1_zs-PI6z_9dF5A_-TcIbDwv-5zWaVsg4GP6SiUA_9s0
Error assuming AWS role: An error occurred (InvalidIdentityToken) when calling the AssumeRoleWithSAML operation: Invalid base64 SAMLResponse (Service: AWSOpenIdDiscoveryService; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AuthSamlInvalidSamlResponseException; Request ID: 80a016bb-17ca-4162-bf68-08f63eba32d2; Proxy: null)
```

@Tutan Ramen in the above link figured to workout something but not sure how.

Code and information is above

Comment: Might help: [Troubleshooting SAML 2.0 federation with AWS - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/troubleshoot_saml.html)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I'd like to share that the federation is working fine on WebBrowser. I am only getting this issue programmatically. Not sure what I am missing on code level.